# How to pronounce ℓ? Is there any other way than 'ell'?

Tags: soft-question, notation, pronunciation

Reading aloud from a graph theory textbook, I encountered the letter ℓ. I assume that most people simply pronounce it 'ell'. However, is there any other way to pronounce it?

Comment: \mathfrak{l} should do the job

Comment: No, just $\ell$ `\ell`. That is the ell.

Comment: If you must distinguish it from other ells, you can specify it is a lower-case, curly ell. But like Jonas said, it is just an ell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the space $\ell^p$, I say "little ell-p."   That is what the Banach Space Cadets at the University of Texas called in when I was a grad student.

Comment: Are there other chapters of the Banach Space Cadets elsewhere? Where do I sign up? Would I get to travel to C-stars? :)

Comment: $\ell$-pun-o.  I think this transformation could be degenerate.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you could pronounce it any way you like, but why would you want to?

The symbol $\ell$ is just a variant form of the lowercase L, drawn in a script style to distinguish it from the number 1 and uppercase I.  I guess you could call it "script ell" if you want to be specific.

(BTW, the official name of the Unicode "letterlike symbol" character ℓ (U+2113) is "Script Small L".)